# How can I push element in an array whenever a function get called?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, http, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

I am implementing infinite scroll. I Have an array named `hotels` which gets data from `$http.get()` method. Now I want to populate a new `array` named `hotelsNew[]` with the value of `hotels` array. But I want to push value in the `hotelsNew` incrementing value of `m` and `j`.

The value of `m` and `j` need to be updated (increment) whenever function `loadMore()` is called. Initial value of `m` is 0 and `j` is 5. When `loadMore()` gets called, again `m` will be 5 and `j` will be 10 and so on.

I am unable to save value of `m` and `j` anywhere because `$http.get()` is asynchronous. Is there any proper way to save values of `m` and `j`, and reuse it when `loadMore()` gets called again?. Maximum `j` value is 40. and when m = j(40), it will stop.

Here is my controller code.

```
 $scope.loadMore = function() {
      $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if(data) { 
          $scope.hotels = data.hotels;
            for(var i = m; i < j; i++) {
              console.log('i=',i);
              $scope.hotelsNew.push($scope.hotels[i]);
              console.log('hotelsNew',$scope.hotelsNew);
            }
         }
     }
```

How can i increment `m` and `j` value ?any idea?

Comment: how much `m` and `j` will be incremented? Is it a fixed value?

Comment: highest value of j is can be 40 (fixed), when m = j it will end, no more update, even if function loadMore() called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `m` and `j` increments same amount each time, you can create a local variable in your controller.

```
var m = 0, j = 5;
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if(data && j < 40) { 
            $scope.hotels = data.hotels;
            for(var i = m; i < j; i++) {
                console.log('i=',i);
                $scope.hotelsNew.push($scope.hotels[i]);
                console.log('hotelsNew',$scope.hotelsNew);
            }
            m += 5;
            j += 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a promise to avoid async call

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
  $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
    if(data) { 
      $scope.hotels = data.hotels;
        for(var i = m; i < j; i++) {
          console.log('i=',i);
          $scope.hotelsNew.push($scope.hotels[i]);
          console.log('hotelsNew',$scope.hotelsNew);
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

see the example for pushing array:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

fruits.push("Kiwi");

get length of data using

$s=Array.sizeof($data)

```
for($i<0;$i<=$s;$i++){//task here}
```

Comment: How  can i increment m and j value ?